# Laravel Mail function error - Trying to get property 'caseno' of non-object

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-mail

I have create the below code for email notification generate. I have added the subject name to 'bookingno' number, it's showing the below error message. please support me.

ErrorException
Trying to get property 'bookingno' of non-object

```
 namespace App\Mail;

 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

 class CustomerTicketReplyHelpdesk extends Mailable
   {
     use Queueable, SerializesModels;

     public function __construct($data)
     {
       $this->data = $data;
     }

     public function build()
     {
      return $this->view('emails.reply-ticket-notification')
            //->subject('RE:New booking number')
            ->subject('RE:Booking Number - ' .$this->data->bookingno)
            ->with('data', $this->data);
     }
 }
```

Comment: `$this->data` is not an object. An array maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. please note the below updated code.

```
  public function build()
   {
    $bookingno = $this->data['bookingno']; 
    return $this->view('emails.reply-ticket-notification')
            ->subject('RE: Booking Number - '.$bookingno)
            ->with('data', $this->data);
   }
```